# How did they do the text graphic set on an angle in TheDailyBeast.com?

Tags: text, positioning

How did they do the text graphic set on an angle in TheDailyBeast.com? Go to this link: https://www.thedailybeast.com/msnbc-host-lawrence-odonnell-accuses-cnn-of-helping-trump-spread-lies?ref=scroll

[image]

Notice just under the headline, a subquote is positioned on an angle? It's not a graphic. It's live text. How did they get the text to be on an angle like that without making a graphic? And is their site Java? CSS?

Answer (score 0):

For issues like this, inspect the code on the page in question, this is a simple [css rotation transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp). When you inspect the HTML, you will find it's quite simple:

```
<div class="Rubric__content">‘WE DON’T BRING ON LIARS’</div>
```

Then have a look at the styles in the dev tools:

```
.Rubric__content {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```